# jQuery loops: Call a function 20 times with one parameter that is a number from 1 to 20

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a question:

I use jQuery and I have created a function called

```
function hide(a) { 
    var item = $('.item:nth-child('+a+')');
    $("body").append(item.text());
}
```

So what should I do, when I want to get the nth-childs 1 to 20? Should I write

```
hide(1);
hide(2);
hide(3);
....
hide(20);
```

Or is there an easier solution?

Comment: You don't have to do `$(div).hide()`. `div.hide()` enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop doesn't make it for you?

```
for (var i=1;i<21;i++)
{ 
  hide(i);
}
```